# Best way to manage 2 apps with basically same code on Github

Tags: git, github, mobile

Here's my scenario: I want two versions of the same app, a paid version and a freemium version.

Of course there will be some differences between them, including app ids but most of the code will be the same.

What I need to know is how to manage it using github in a way that I can make changes that affect both of them while keeping their specific code intact.

Let's say I need to change some text in both apps, add a feature or fix a bug that affects both of them, is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what @CodeWizard explained…

- It's perfectly possible to develop both versions on parallel branches
  and use regular merges to bring changes between one of them to another.

  Typically you'd develop the "reference" code on a branch and
  the "freemium" version would sit on another branch, differ only in the
  "crippling" bits, and would periodically receive updates from the
  "reference" branch where all the features and bug fixes are done
  (unless specific to the "freemium" version, of course).

  The branch with the "reference" code may then be consideres as
  "upstream" for the branch with the freemium customizations.

  The idea is that merging won't unconditionally overwrite the receiving
  ("ours") side with the content from the side being merged ("theirs")—that is,
  if we have freemium customizations in a file `foo/bar.java`, and the
  pile of changes being merged from the "reference" version does not touch
  that file, its contents will be left "as is" (that is, as we want it to),
  with our customizations intact.

  In the compilcated cases—where there are changes done to the files
  which contain customizations—you might need to resolve conflicts,
  but this is normal.

  "The trick" for this setup to work is that Git has reasonably smart
  merging machinery and detects already merged textual changes just fine to
  not flag bogus conflicts. So it's fine to periodically do "integration
  merges" from one branch to another—they will naturally bring only what
  was changed.
- You might again use the two branches as explained above—with the
  branch containing the "reference" code serving as upstream to the
  branch with freemium mods,—but this time use rebasing.

  With rebasing you periodically rebase the (whole) series of commits
  which implements freemium customizations on top of the updated baseline
  branch.

  The upside of this approach is that your customizations are always
  "on top" of the baseline branch, and supposedly this approach is the easiest
  to reason about (once you actually "get" what `git rebase` does).

  The downside is that the series with customizations will be re-written
  (with the SHA-1 names of its commits changing) each time you rebase.

---

*Update.*

The first approach.

Let's pretend the branch "master" is the "reference", "upstream"
version and the "freemium" branch keeps crippling stuff.

Here's how to implement a feature/do a bugfix.

1. Fork a feature branch and record any number of commits on it.

   ```
   $ git checkout -b cool_feat master
   ...hack hack hack
   $ git commit
   ...
   ```
2. Merge it back to the mainline:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git merge cool_feat
   ```
3. Get the same changed in the "freemium"—that is, "reintegrate"
   the mainline into "freemium":

   ```
   $ git checkout freemium
   $ git merge master
   ```
4. Rinse, repeat.

This way, features are implemented / bugs are fixed on the "mainline"
branch and then get merged into the branch which naturally follows it
while containing the customizations.

Comment: I'm really a beginner regarding git so let me see if I understood. I can have a parent branch, let's say the master as the "reference" and two other child branches from this parent, the paid and freemium. Then I can create, let's say, bug-fixing branches from the master and push them to the two main children. Is that it? If so, that's exactly what I would like to do. I'd really appreciate if you could add some commented git code to your answer.

Comment: No. There's no such thing as "pushing a branch into another branch".

Comment: Lol I guess I wasn't clear enough because your update does exactly what I was thinking. Maybe I used the wrong words. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in several ways:

1. Develop each version in each branch and use `git cherry-pick` for "passing" content between the braches
2. Use different branches for the

   - "common" code and branch for shared content
   - v1 & v2 for the diffrent code
3. use git submodule instead of branches as described in the previous step
4. Develop using build tool/script in the following way: develop on a single branch and your build script should pack only the required code.

Im usually using way #4. Having a single branch and the code divided into folders. The build tool collects the required content per application and packs it. This way I can manage the code in a simple way

Comment: Thanks mate. But the other answer is more complete and more on point to what I needed.